# Flutter: DefaulltTabController with single child TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the following code snippet to create a tab bar with 20 tabs along with their views (you can copy-paste the code to try it out, it complies with no problems):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabBody extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tabNumber;
  const TabBody({required this.tabNumber, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabBody> createState() => _TabBodyState();
}

class _TabBodyState extends State<TabBody> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print(
        'inside init state for ${widget.tabNumber}'); //<--- I want this line to execute only once
    super.initState();
  }

  getDataForTab() {
    //getting data for widget.tabNumber
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Text('This is tab #${widget.tabNumber} body')),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  List<Text> get _tabs {
    var list = [for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) i];
    List<Text> tabs = list.map((i) => Text('Tab Title $i')).toList();
    return tabs;
  }

  List<TabBody> get _tabsBodies {
    var list = [for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) i];
    List<TabBody> bodies = list.map((i) => TabBody(tabNumber: i)).toList();
    return bodies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabs.length,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: _tabs,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              children: _tabsBodies, //<--- i want this to be one child only
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to do the following but couldn't find a way for that:

1. I want to let the TabBarView to have only one child of type `TabBody` not a list of `_tabsBodies`, i.e. the print statement in `initState` should execute once.
2. I want to execute the function `getDataForTab` every time the tab is changed to another tab.

so in general I need to refresh the tab body page for each tab selection, in contrast to the default implementation of the `DefaultTabController` widget which requires to have `n` number of tab bodies for `n` number of tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do three things:

- Remove the `TabBarView`. You don't need it if you want to have a single widget. (Having a `TabBar` does not require you to have a `TabBarView`)
- Create your own `TabController` so you can pass the current index to the `TabBody`.
- Listen to the `TabController` and update the state to pass the new index to `TabBody`.

Here's a fully runnable example and that you can copy and paste to [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final tabController =
      TabController(length: 20, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController.addListener(() {
      if (tabController.previousIndex != tabController.index && !tabController.indexIsChanging) {
        print('setting state'); // <~~ will print one time now
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  List<Text> get _tabs {
    var list = [for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) i];
    List<Text> tabs = list.map((i) => Text('Tab Title $i')).toList();
    return tabs;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true, tabs: _tabs, controller: tabController),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBody(tabNumber: tabController.index),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TabBody extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tabNumber;
  const TabBody({required this.tabNumber, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabBody> createState() => _TabBodyState();
}

class _TabBodyState extends State<TabBody> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print(
        'inside init state for ${widget.tabNumber}'); //<--- I want this line to execute only once
    super.initState();
  }

  getDataForTab() {
    //getting data for widget.tabNumber
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Text('This is tab #${widget.tabNumber} body')),
    );
  }
}
```

Few notes about the example:

- when you create a TabController, you'll need a ticker. You can use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to make the class itself a ticker (hence: `vsync: this`). Alternatively, you can create your own and pass it to `TabController.vsync` parameter.

```dart
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final tabController = TabController(length: 20, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
```

- Here we are listening to the tab controller whenever the tabs changes:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController.addListener(() {
      if (tabController.previousIndex != tabController.index && !tabController.indexIsChanging) {
        print('setting state'); // <~~ will print one time now
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }
```

edit: you'll also need to dispose the `tabController`. I updated the code above.

Comment: while this is an excellent solution but it has two problems: 1) `setState` is called twice on each tab selection. 2) I lost the ability to switch between tabs with finger slide like what's implemented with `TabBarView`  in the question's code snippet.

Comment: @JAHelia I updated the answer where the first problem is fixed. I'm not sure if the second one is a possible if you want `TabBody` to be initialized once only and be able to animate between one `TabBody` to another `TabBody` which what `TabBarView` was doing (internally it uses `PageView`). You could definitely do a trick to mimic the behavior using `GestureDetector.onHorizontalDrag....` but the code can be involved a bit since you need to animate the `TabBody` along with the Gesture and manage when it should update the index, etc.

Comment: do you have an idea on what's the best possible candidate place to put the `getDataForTab ` call in ? giving that this function is going to be async, I found it  unsuitable to place its call in the `build` method.

Comment: You can use `FutureBuilder` here to build the widget so you can show a loading indicator when loading, error when it has an error and the actual widget when the data arrives. If `getDataForTab` is a network call, you may wanna do it differently or at least cache the data so `getDataForTab` isn't making a network call on each build (eg user goes to another tab then comes back to the same tab). If you have the cached data, then you can pass it to `FutureBuilder` as `value: data != null ? Future.value(data) : getDataForTab()` and then in `getDataForTab` assign `data`.. or something similar.